# React-native, render a button click dynamically

Tags: react-native

i want to generate a button click dynamically for a `TouchableOpacity` in react-native, 
i didn't find anything about that,

all i want is to call the TouchableOpacity onPress from a fuction (or see its effect on the button)

in titanium we were doing $.button.click
i tried using Animated but no luck
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

so can anybody help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really inadvisable but something like this *should work*:

```
simulatePress() {
  this.touchable.props.onPress();
}

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity ref={component => this.touchable = component} onPress={() => console.log('onPress')}>
          <Text>Tap me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity
    );
}
```

Really though, what you are trying to achieve? There is likely a better way to do it.

Comment: thank you, this worked in calling the method, but not in simulation the effect of the click, i resolved the problem using animatable and i replaced the opacity change with a pulse ...,

Comment: what if I have two buttons?

Comment: I disagree with this being really inadvisable. If you have a component with children inputs/buttons that has to use it's parent components properties, but you want external controls then this a good solution.