# Programmatically clicking button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a button with a field testID

```
<Button testID='someButton' onPress={someButtonClick}/>
```

Is there any way to programatically click a button with given testID ?

Comment: Can you add some code for the button that you've defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-native, render a button click dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527446/react-native-render-a-button-click-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete implementation of one button pressing another.

```
import React from "react"
import { View, Button  } from 'react-native';

const someButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("button was pressed");
}

export class PressButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
    clickButton() {
        this.button.props.onPress();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="another button" 
                    onPress={() => { this.clickButton()}}
                />
                <Button title="some button" testID='someButton' 
                onPress={() => { someButtonClick() }}
                    ref={(button) => {this.button = button; }}
                />          
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Note the following

- you need a ref in order to access the button.
- onPress() is the correct method in React Native, not click()
- the event handlers are in props.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a ref.

```
<Button id={buttonId}
  onClick={e => console.log(e.target)}
  ref={(button) => { this.myButton = button; }}
  // Or something like this:
  ref={component => this.myButton = component}
/>
```

And then you can access that ref somewhere else in your code:

```
myFunction = () => {
  this.myButton.click()
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple buttons with different "testID"s , how can I use this code to click a button with given "testID" ?

Comment: You put different refs on different buttons. so `ref={component => this.myButton1 = component}` and `ref={component => this.myButton2 = component}` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
const uploadbtn = useRef();
```

I am hiding this button to press it programmatically

```
 <Button
    ref={uploadbtn}
    buttonStyle={{ width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0, display: "none" }}
    onPress={pickImage}
  />
```

And then use a function like this to press the button

```
  const test = () => {
    uploadbtn.current.handleOnPress();
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in render code.

```
<div className="container" hidden >
   <button onClick={this.submit} ref={(button) => { this.btn = button }} />
</div>
```

in function

```
btn = () => {
   this.btn.click()
}
```

in else code

```
this.btn()
```

Comment: Question says "React Native"

Answer (score -3):

in render() function

```
 <button type='button' onClick="{this.btnClickFunc.bind(this)}">buton</button>
```

and

```
 function btnClickFunc(e){
    var value = e.target.value;

    }
```

I Hope worked for you

Comment: This is not at all what he is asking for.

Comment: I am asking different question.