# How to activate the TouchablePpacity onPress from javascript in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react native and I don't know how to auto click a `TouchableOpacity`.

With `jquery` and HTML it would be `$("#id").click();` but in react native I don't know how to manipulate the `onPress` with javascript so that it is pressed alone.

Comment: I don't know the exact use-case what you're looking for but you can simply call by yourself a function which will be called when `onPress` is triggered. If you explain the use-case much more detailed, we can help you a better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import {TouchableOpacity }  from 'react-native';
...
 const function=()=>{
      console.log('pressed!');
    };
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>function()}>
       <Text> Press me!<Text/>
    <TouchableOpacity/>
```

Try this and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you should call a function, Not a trigger:

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>yourfunction()}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

If you insist on trigger on touchables... you should use useRef hook or ref,

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527446/react-native-render-a-button-click-dynamically)