# How to simulate key press event on button press in React Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a `<TextInput />`. I am trying to simulate key press event on "submit" button where I added it below the TextInput. Here code:

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.textInput}
  onSubmitEditing={event => onSubmitEditButton(event.nativeEvent.text)}
/>
<TouchableHighlight onPress={"HERE I AM TRYING TO SIMULATE ENTER-KEY PRESS IN ORDER TO TRIGGER OnSubmitEditing EVENT"} style={{position:"absolute", top:50}}>
  <Text>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight
```

Comment: Here is a very similar question with an accepted answer. Hope this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530232/4781064

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want onSubmitEditing to do the same thing on a button press, then just call onSubmitEditing in onPress of your button. But this would require storing the text within an input externally:

```js
const [text, setText] = useState('')
const onSubmit = ()=>{
  // do stuff with text in textinput
  console.log(text)
  Keyboard.dismiss()
}
return (
  <TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={setText}
    onSubmitEditing={onSubmit}
  />
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={onSubmit}
    style={{position:"absolute", top:50}}
  >
    <Text>Submit</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
)
```

Comment: But I don't want to use setState hook at onChangeText because it is being called at every key press. Therefore I tried to simulate "Enter" key press and use only onSubmitEditing